# curl only download if timestamp on server is newer

Tags: curl, timestamps

`curl --help` didn't help me much. I couldn't easily find if such an option exists.

Apparently `wget -N` is as close as possible to what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not quite clear. Are you saying that currently, your `curl` only downloads a file if the timestamp on the server is newer, and this is unwanted behavior, or are you saying that you look for a way to make `curl` only download files _if_ the version on the remote server is newer? Please edit your question to make the intention clearer.

Comment: It's unclear what the remote document should be newer _than_ or in what sense the document should be newer (a timestamp, version string or something else).

Answer (score 2):

`curl -z …` aka. `curl --time-cond …` is what you are looking for.

See https://curl.se/docs/manual.html, Section *Time Conditions*

Comment: That is not an equivalent of `wget -N`. `curl -z` requires a timestamp argument, where as `wget -N` automatically uses the timestamp of the local file.

Comment: How to calculate the zflag  https://superuser.com/a/908523